# Iterate through all rows of specific page using Freeform?

Tags: templating, plugin-freeform

Documentation (http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/template-objects/page.html#usage-in-templates) says you can iterate through all rows on CURRENT page or entire form.

I need all rows/fields at once but separated by page for an accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or I could actually read all the documentation: Method `getRows()`

As in `{% for row in page.getRows() %}`